# Test class for the zenkraft process class

Tags: apex

I have created the test class for the zenkraft process, but when I run this test class it stops the code coverage after the following line

i.e batchId = zkusps.BulkShipmentInterface.validateBulkShipment(bulkShipmentId);

and it shows the following error message 
i.e
**System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.**

Is there any mock class for this test class.Please help me

My apex class:

global class MakeShipmentQueue implements Database.Batchable{

```
private Id bulkShipmentId;
private String batchId;      
public final String workingObject = 'ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c';
global String scope;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    String orderStatus = 'Initiated';
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c WHERE ChargentOrders__Status__c = :orderStatus]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c> scope) {

    if(scope.size() > 0){

        List<zkusps__ShippingPreference__c> caseShipmateList = [SELECT zkusps__CompanyName__c, zkusps__ShippingCity__c, zkusps__preference__c, zkusps__shippingSenderEmailDefault__c,
                                                                zkusps__shippingSenderPhoneDefault__c, zkusps__ShippingState__c, zkusps__ShippingStreet__c, 
                                                                zkusps__ShippingPostalCode__c, zkusps__LabelImageTypeDefault__c FROM zkusps__ShippingPreference__c LIMIT 1];


        if ( ! caseShipmateList.isEmpty() ) {

            // 1. zkusps__BulkShipment__c object
            zkusps__BulkShipment__c bulkShipment = new zkusps__BulkShipment__c (
                zkusps__BillingPreference__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__preference__c
            );
            insert bulkShipment;
            bulkShipmentId = bulkShipment.Id;

            List<zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c> customAddressSourceList = [SELECT Id FROM zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c WHERE zkusps__CustomAddressSourceObject__c = 
                                                                            :workingObject LIMIT 1];


            Set<Id> orderIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c order : scope) {
                orderIds.add(order.Id);
            }

            /* Get all unshiped Orders */
            List<ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c> orders = [ SELECT ChargentOrders__Shipping_City__c, ChargentOrders__Shipping_Country__c, ChargentOrders__Billing_Email__c, 
                                                                ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c, ChargentOrders__Billing_Last_Name__c, ChargentOrders__Billing_Phone__c, 
                                                                ChargentOrders__Shipping_State__c, ChargentOrders__Shipping_Address__c, ChargentOrders__Shipping_Zip_Postal__c 
                                                                FROM ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c WHERE Id IN : orderIds];



            if ( ! customAddressSourceList.isEmpty() ) {

                // 2. zkusps__QueuedShipment__c object
                zkusps__QueuedShipment__c[] queueItems = new zkusps__QueuedShipment__c[]{};

                    for(ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c order : orders){

                        zkusps__QueuedShipment__c queuedShipment = new zkusps__QueuedShipment__c (
                            zkusps__BulkShipment__c = bulkShipment.Id,
                            zkusps__LabelImageType__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__LabelImageTypeDefault__c,
                            zkusps__ServiceType__c = 'Domestic: Express',
                            zkusps__PackagingType__c = 'Parcel',   

                            // sender info
                            zkusps__SenderName__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__CompanyName__c,
                            zkusps__SenderCity__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__ShippingCity__c,
                            zkusps__SenderCompany__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__CompanyName__c,
                            zkusps__SenderEmail__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__shippingSenderEmailDefault__c,
                            zkusps__SenderPhone__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__shippingSenderPhoneDefault__c,
                            zkusps__SenderState__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__ShippingState__c,
                            zkusps__SenderStreet__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__ShippingStreet__c,
                            zkusps__SenderPostalCode__c = caseShipmateList.get(0).zkusps__ShippingPostalCode__c,

                            // recipient info 
                            zkusps__RecipientCity__c = order.ChargentOrders__Shipping_City__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientCompany__c = '',
                            zkusps__RecipientCountry__c = 'US',
                            zkusps__RecipientEmail__c = order.ChargentOrders__Billing_Email__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientName__c = order.ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientPhone__c = order.ChargentOrders__Billing_Phone__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientState__c = order.ChargentOrders__Shipping_State__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientStreet__c = order.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Address__c,
                            zkusps__RecipientPostalCode__c = order.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Zip_Postal__c,
                            zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c = customAddressSourceList.get(0).id,
                            zkusps__CustomAddressSourceRecordId__c = order.Id);

                        queueItems.add(queuedShipment);                                        
                    }
                    insert queueItems;

                List<zkusps__QueuedShipment__c> queuedShipmentIds = [SELECT Id FROM zkusps__QueuedShipment__c WHERE zkusps__CustomAddressSourceRecordId__c IN : orderIds];

                // 3. zkusps__QueuedPackage__c object
                zkusps__QueuedPackage__c[] queuedPackages = new zkusps__QueuedPackage__c[]{};
                for(zkusps__QueuedShipment__c queueId : queuedShipmentIds){

                    zkusps__QueuedPackage__c queuedPackage = new zkusps__QueuedPackage__c (
                        zkusps__DeclaredValue__c = 0,
                        zkusps__WeightPounds__c = 0,
                        zkusps__QueuedShipment__c = queueId.Id          
                    );
                    queuedPackages.add(queuedPackage);
                }
                insert queuedPackages;    

                // Validate shipping address 
                batchId = zkusps.BulkShipmentInterface.validateBulkShipment(bulkShipmentId);

                zkusps__BulkShipmentStatus__c statuses = new zkusps__BulkShipmentStatus__c();

                statuses.zkusps__BulkShipment__c = bulkShipmentId;
                statuses.zkusps__Status__c = 'VALIDATION_COMPLETED';
                insert statuses;

                batchId = zkusps.BulkShipmentInterface.processBulkShipment(bulkShipmentId); 

            }else {

                System.debug('Invalid Custom Address Source.');
                return;  
            }   
        }else {

            System.debug('Invalid Preference.');
            return;
        } 

    } else{

        System.debug('0 order found with status "Initiated"');
        return;
    }        
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}
```

}

Its Test class is:

@isTest
public class MakeShipmentQueueTest {

```
@testsetup
/* For data test */
static void testData() {

    /* Order info */
    ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c chargeOrder = new ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c();
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Status__c = 'Initiated';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_City__c = 'Chicago';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Country__c = 'United States';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Email__c = 'francine@apothecarybeauty.com';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c = 'Erin';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Last_Name__c = 'Lang';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Phone__c = '(312) 813-9876';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_State__c = 'IL';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Address__c = '1050 Marshfield Ave #3';
    chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Zip_Postal__c = '60622';
    insert chargeOrder;

    /* zenkraft preference info */
    zkusps__Preference__c testbillingzkusps = new zkusps__Preference__c();
    testbillingzkusps.zkusps__accountContactEmail__c ='salesforce@mcnabbus.com';
    testbillingzkusps.zkusps__accountContactName__c ='Mcnabb SalesforceAdmin';
    insert testbillingzkusps;

    /* zenkraft shipping preference info*/
    zkusps__ShippingPreference__c testzkusps = new zkusps__ShippingPreference__c();
    testzkusps.zkusps__CompanyName__c = 'McNabb Technologies LLC';
    testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingCity__c = 'Chicago';
    testzkusps.zkusps__preference__c = testbillingzkusps.Id;
    testzkusps.zkusps__shippingSenderEmailDefault__c = 'salesforce@mcnabbus.com';
    testzkusps.zkusps__shippingSenderPhoneDefault__c = '3109785333';
    testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingState__c = 'IL';
    testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingStreet__c = '1621 W Walnut St';
    testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingPostalCode__c = '60612';
    testzkusps.zkusps__LabelImageTypeDefault__c = 'ZPLII';
    insert testzkusps;

    /* zenkraft bulkshipment info */
    zkusps__BulkShipment__c testbulkShipment = new zkusps__BulkShipment__c ();
    testbulkShipment.zkusps__BillingPreference__c = testbillingzkusps.Id;
    insert testbulkShipment;

    /* zenkraft custom address source info */
    zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c testcustomadd = new zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c();
    testcustomadd.zkusps__CustomAddressSourceObject__c = 'ChargentOrders__ChargentOrder__c';
    insert testcustomadd;

    /* zenkraft queued shipment info */
    zkusps__QueuedShipment__c testqueuedship = new zkusps__QueuedShipment__c();
    testqueuedship.zkusps__BulkShipment__c =testbulkShipment.Id;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__LabelImageType__c =testzkusps.zkusps__labelImageTypeDefault__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__ServiceType__c ='Domestic: Express';
    testqueuedship.zkusps__PackagingType__c ='Parcel';
    // sender info
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderName__c = testzkusps.zkusps__CompanyName__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderCity__c = testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingCity__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderCompany__c = testzkusps.zkusps__CompanyName__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderEmail__c = testzkusps.zkusps__shippingSenderEmailDefault__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderPhone__c = testzkusps.zkusps__shippingSenderPhoneDefault__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderState__c = testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingState__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderStreet__c = testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingStreet__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__SenderPostalCode__c = testzkusps.zkusps__ShippingPostalCode__c;
    // recipient info
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientCity__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_City__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientCompany__c = '';
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientCountry__c = 'US';
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientEmail__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Email__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientName__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_First_Name__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientPhone__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Billing_Phone__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientState__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_State__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientStreet__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Address__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__RecipientPostalCode__c = chargeOrder.ChargentOrders__Shipping_Zip_Postal__c;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__CustomAddressSource__c = testcustomadd.id;
    testqueuedship.zkusps__CustomAddressSourceRecordId__c = chargeOrder.Id;
    insert testqueuedship;

    /* zenkraft queued package info */
    zkusps__QueuedPackage__c testqueuedpack = new zkusps__QueuedPackage__c();
    testqueuedpack.zkusps__DeclaredValue__c = 0;
    testqueuedpack.zkusps__WeightPounds__c = 0;
    testqueuedpack.zkusps__QueuedShipment__c = testqueuedship.Id;
    insert testqueuedpack;

    /* zenkraft bulk shipment status info */
    zkusps__BulkShipmentStatus__c testbulkship = new zkusps__BulkShipmentStatus__c();
    testbulkship.zkusps__BulkShipment__c = testbulkShipment.Id;
    testbulkship.zkusps__Status__c = 'VALIDATION_COMPLETED';
    insert testbulkship;

}

/* For Scheduler test */
static testMethod void testScheduler() {
    System.schedule('Test Checker', '0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *', new ZenKraftBatchScheduler());
}

/* For Batch test */
static testMethod void testBatch() {
    MakeShipmentQueue objBatch = new MakeShipmentQueue();
    Database.executeBatch(objBatch);
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot see Test.startTest and Test.stopTest for the batch class. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_batch_2.htm

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the call that you are making from the execute method of a batchable is causing another batchable to execute and as the message explains that is not supported. I would expect the same error to occur when the code is used in a non-test context i.e. the test is exposing a design problem that needs fixing. But worth confirming the problem in the non-test context first.

A simple fix would be to find an equivalent method to `zkusps.BulkShipmentInterface.validateBulkShipment` that runs synchronously: you will need to check the set of methods available and may need to contact the package supplier.

If no such method is available then you have a bigger problem in that you will need to seek out a design using some combination of batchable/queuable/future/synchronous code that avoids this nested batchable problem. Or are you sure you need your batchable?

**PS**

I see there is some documentation such as [USPS Bulk Shipping Platform Developer Guide](https://support.zenkraft.com/kb/usps-bulk-shipping-platform-developer-guide-2/) that suggests the API is largely asynchronous. Probably best if you contact their support and discuss your needs - they may be able to suggest an API or pattern that will meet them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use our sync methods.

```
BulkShipmentInterface.validateBulkShipment(bulkShipmentId)
```

and

```
BulkShipmentInterface.processBulkShipment(bulkShipmentId)
```

are async methods.

We have sync methods that you can use:

```
BulkShipmentInterface.validateBulkShipmentSynchronous(bulkShipmentId)
```

and

```
BulkShipmentInterface.processBulkShipmentSynchronous(bulkShipmentId)
```

You should use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() around the Database.executeBatch(objBatch) in Test class.

For example:

```
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(objBatch);
Test.stopTest();
```